# Get daily orders count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, orders

I want to get daily order count of daily whenever an order is posted. I wrote the below code to give a notification on slack whenever there is an order. As a result of displaying $result it showing the current order amount rather than the total order count of the day.

```
function wp_slack_woocommerce_order_status_completed2( $events ) {
    $events['woocommerce_order_status_processing'] = array(

        // Action in WooCommerce to hook in to get the message.
        'action' => 'woocommerce_order_status_processing',

        // Description appears in integration setting.
        'description' => __( 'Whenever we receive an order', 'slack-woocommerce' ),

        // Message to deliver to channel. Returns false will prevent
        // notification delivery.
        'message' => function( $order_id ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            $date = is_callable( array( $order, 'get_date_completed' ) )
                ? $order->get_date_completed()
                : $order->completed_date;
            $url  = add_query_arg(
                array(
                    'post'   => $order_id,
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                admin_url( 'post.php' )
            );

            $user_id = is_callable( array( $order, 'get_user_id' ) )
                ? $order->get_user_id()
                : $order->user_id;

            if ( $user_id ) {
                $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $user_info ) ) {
                if ( $user_info->first_name || $user_info->last_name ) {
                    $username = esc_html( ucfirst( $user_info->first_name ) . ' ' . ucfirst( $user_info->last_name ) );
                } else {
                    $username = esc_html( ucfirst( $user_info->display_name ) );
                }
            } else {
                $billing_first_name = is_callable( array( $order, 'get_billing_first_name' ) )
                    ? $order->get_billing_first_name()
                    : $order->billing_first_name;
                $billing_last_name = is_callable( array( $order, 'get_billing_last_name' ) )
                    ? $order->get_billing_last_name()
                    : $order->billing_last_name;

                if ( $billing_first_name || $billing_last_name ) {
                    $username = trim( $billing_first_name . ' ' . $billing_last_name );
                } else {
                    $username = __( 'Guest', 'slack-woocommerce' );
                }
            }
            global $wpdb;

            $date_from = '2018-02-27';
            $date_to = '2018-02-28';
            $post_status = implode("','", array('wc-processing', 'wc-completed') );

            $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT count(*) as total FROM $wpdb->posts 
                        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
                        AND post_status IN ('{$post_status}')
                        AND post_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}  00:00:00' AND '{$date_to} 23:59:59'
                    ");

            // Remove HTML tags generated by WooCommerce.
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'wp_strip_all_tags', 10, 1 );
            $total = html_entity_decode( $order->get_formatted_order_total() );
            remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'wp_strip_all_tags', 10 );
            //$data2=WC_API_Reports::get_sales_report(  );
            // Returns the message to be delivered to Slack.
            return apply_filters( 'slack_woocommerce_order_status_completed_message',
                sprintf(
                    __( 'Reveived new order with amount *%1$s*. Made by *%2$s* on *%3$s*. <%4$s|See detail> %s', 'slack-woocommerce' ),
                    $total,
                    $username,
                    $date,
                    $url,
                    $resullt
                ),
                $order
            );
        },
    );

    return $events;
}
add_filter( 'slack_get_events', 'wp_slack_woocommerce_order_status_completed2' );
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the daily order count you can use this custom function that will return the order count for the current day or the order count for a specific defined date:

```
function get_daily_orders_count( $date = 'now' ){
    if( $date == 'now' ){
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $date_string = "> '$date'";
    } else {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $date ));
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $date ) + 86400 );
        $date_string = "BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date2'";
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT DISTINCT count(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND p.post_date $date_string
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-on-hold','wc-processing','wc-completed')
    " );
    return $result;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

1) To get the orders count for the current date:

```
$orders_count = get_daily_orders_count();
```

2) To get the orders count for a specific date (with a format like `2018-02-28`):

```
// Get orders count for february 25th 2018 (for example)
$orders_count = get_daily_orders_count('2018-02-25');
```

Comment: The wordpress order  button stops working when I use this code.

Comment: @FahadUddin I have updated my answer. Please try it, as should perfectly work now. I have just forgot to remove a custom testing function, that was making that issue in your case...

Comment: @FahadUddin Very strange… For me it's working perfectly for both examples cases.

Comment: I will test again and get back to you.